# How can I get the gradients of two losses in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, gradient-descent

I am trying to get the gradients of two losses in the following code snippet but all I get is None (AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘data’)

```
img = img.to(device)
#img.requires_grad = True
input = model(img)
input_prediction = input.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]

btarget = torch.tensor(2).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
x_prime.requires_grad = True
x_prime_output = model(x_prime)
x_prime_pred =  x_prime_output.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]

l_target_loss = F.nll_loss(x_prime_output, btarget)
# model.zero_grad()
l_target_loss.retain_grad()
l_target_loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
target_grad = l_target_loss.grad.data

l_argmax_loss = F.nll_loss(x_prime_output, input_prediction.squeeze(0))
l_argmax_loss.retain_grad()
l_argmax_loss.backward()
l_argmax_grad = l_argmax_loss.grad.data
```

when I tried getting `target_grad` and `l_argmax_grad`, I get None.

Edit: I am actually trying to get the gradient of the `l_target_loss` w.r.t to the input `x` and the gradient of the  `l_argmax_loss` w.r.t to the input `x` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain the gradient on that tensor with [`retain_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.retain_grad.html), by default it is not cached in memory:

```
>>> l_target_loss.retain_grad()
>>> l_target_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I'm setting a break point to print out the gradient values and they are both 1's. Is this  just a coincidence

Comment: Yes, since you're looking at the gradient of the output!

Comment: I feel that I'm doing something wrong. What I actually want is the gradient of the ```target_loss``` with respect to the input (x) and gradient of the ```l_argmax_loss``` with respect to the input (x). The input ```x```  is ```img``` in the code snippet above. How do I go about it please @Ivan

Comment: Just to clarify: what `L.grad` contains is the gradient of `L` with respect to the input of `L`, here `1`. However, what you are asking for here is `dL/dx`, which is essentially `x.grad`, ***assuming*** you have backpropagated the gradient with `L.backward()`!
If you perform two backward passes, for example `L1.backward()` then `L2.backward()`... you will end up with `x.grad` corresponding to `d(L1+L2)/dx`!